# Php / mysql query to update data table through foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I have 3 php tables, which are response, question and answer. the response table is dynamically retrieved from mysql and displayed on my website. the response table displays values from the question and answer table through foreign keys.

I want to edit a field in the answer table through the response table which is being displayed, however i do not know how to build the query for it to be able to do this. the description field in the answer table is the one which i want to edit.

I have tried researching on how to do this, but as i am new to php / Mysql i have not found a solution.

Please see below a designer view of my tables

[image: Designer view of my data tables]

Comment: _php tables_...?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton My php tables are shown if you select the link at the bottom

Comment: "PHP tables" is not a thing. Maybe you mean "database tables". As a note screenshots are almost always the worst possible way to convey this information: We can't run them as code, we can't use them to reproduce your problem. Instead, if relevant, include the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for any important tables.

Comment: Please add what you tried so that it can be reporduced. Give some [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)